# Is there a way to count the sorted queryset using count instead of length?

Tags: python-3.x, django, sorting, django-templates, django-queryset

I am working on search part of my project. On one of my filter, I have to use `sorted()` function. Code:-

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
posts = sorted(posts, key=lambda obj: obj.titleFilter())
```

But, in other filters in the project, I don't have to use sorted as it can be done with `django annotate` and so on. So, in the template I usually have to do `posts.count` except for the title filter.

My template, code:-

```
<div>{{ posts.count }} results found.</div>
```

I know, I can use if cases in template to work and apply `length` function like:

```
<div>
    {% if title_filter %}
        {{ posts|length }}
    {% else %}
        {{ posts.count }}
    {% endif %} results found.
</div>
```

Also, I am not sure if length should be fine as there were some article not to use `length` for querysets.

Thank you!!! Feel free to ask.

Comment: `sorted` is no longer a `QuerySet`. This is one of the reasons why it is often better to look if you can order with `.order_by()`.

Comment: But, I cannot do it with ``order_by``, so I had to use sorted.

Comment: well since it is not a queryset, it thus has no `count` anymore. The `posts` here are a *list*, not a `QuerySet`.

Comment: Then, will there be a problem if I use ``length`` in template. Will it make difference between count. For now, it shows no difference btw.

Comment: no, there is no difference. But using a `QuerySet` is often better, since it is lazy, and can easily chain with extra calls.

Comment: Thanks, then I have to use if conditions as I used```sorted()```

Answer (score 1):

After doing sorted posts is no longer a QuerySet.
You can do this

```py
posts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
count = posts.count()
posts = sorted(posts, key=lambda obj: obj.titleFilter())
```

send count as a variable

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But, as length does not make difference as per @Willem. I will stick with previous one. But, thanks.